# How to authenticate /app/rest/** if called from another service?

Tags: jhipster

Is there a builtin mechanism to authenticate /app/rest/** if the request is coming from another service ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by spring security configuration. Try adding this configuration in `SecurityConfiguration`

```
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/app/rest/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
```